# Javascript string encoding/decoding

Tags: javascript, string

I have some strings like `s0 = "\"first line,\\nsecond line,\\n\""`, and some other strings like `s1 = "first line,\nsecond line,\n"`, where `s0` is like the string representation of the whole `s1`. I wonder if there's any easy way to convert `s0` and `s1` both way. I understand I could do replace. However, there might be a whole lot of other escape sequences to take care of.

Comment: `JSON.parse(s0)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `JSON` methods:

```js
s0 = "\"first line,\\nsecond line,\\n\"",
s1 = "first line,\nsecond line,\n"

console.log('Parse s0 ::', JSON.parse(s0))
console.log('Stringify s1 ::', JSON.stringify(s1))
```